# Importing actionbarsherlock on Android Studio 0.8.9

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I have a problem when importing `ActionBarSherlock`. I'm using **Android Studio 0.8.9**. I modify my `build.gradle` file according [this](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html). But I got errors telling that `can not resolve symbol R`.

Here are the error messages after importing ActionBarSherlock:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugTestSources]
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices5089Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
D:\CodeBunch\Android\DataBudaya\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.actionbarsherlock\actionbarsherlock\4.4.0\res\values\values.xml
Error:Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "title" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "icon" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "logo" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "backgroundStacked" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "customNavigationLayout" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "homeLayout" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "progressBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "indeterminateProgressStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "progressBarPadding" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "itemPadding" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "initialActivityCount" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "iconifiedByDefault" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "queryHint" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarTabStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarTabBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarTabTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionOverflowButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarSplitStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarWidgetTheme" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarSize" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionBarItemBackground" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionMenuTextAppearance" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionMenuTextColor" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionModeStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionModeCloseButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionModeBackground" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionModeSplitBackground" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionModeCloseDrawable" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionModeShareDrawable" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionModePopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "selectableItemBackground" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "spinnerDropDownItemStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchDropdownBackground" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchViewCloseIcon" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchViewGoIcon" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchViewSearchIcon" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchViewVoiceIcon" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchViewEditQuery" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchViewEditQueryBackground" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchViewTextField" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchViewTextFieldRight" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "textColorSearchUrl" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "searchResultListItemHeight" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultTitle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "listPreferredItemHeightSmall" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingRight" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "textAppearanceListItemSmall" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "dividerVertical" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "actionButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "homeAsUpIndicator" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "dropDownListViewStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "windowSplitActionBar" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "listPopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "activityChooserViewStyle" has already been defined
```

I will appreciate any helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the `appcompat-v7` and `ActionBarSherlock` together.

You can't do it, because they both provide the same style attributes.

You have to remove one of these libraries.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti is there any way I can use both? 
I am stuck in different scenario where I have to make a custom ActionBarActivity and I am using a library thats also has AppCompact in it.I just have the SDK, i cant fork it and change it

Comment: @ShahrozKhan91 With Material Design,it's time to migrate to AppCompat.